# Why not update the value state unselected terms

Tags: react-native

Why not update the value state unselected in the following component when the variable terms is actually updated and displayed in the console.

[**View source and result here**](https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-architecture-66ip9?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach is storing the IDs and if the Item ID exist in the array then checked.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  CheckBox,
  TouchableOpacity
} from "react-native";
const terms = [
  {
    term_id: 21,
    name: "Clothing",
    checked: false,
    children: [
      {
        term_id: 24,
        name: "Accessories",
        checked: false,
        children: [
          {
            term_id: 25,
            name: "Scarf",
            checked: false,
            children: []
          },
          {
            term_id: 22,
            name: "Tshirts",
            checked: false,
            children: []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    term_id: 26,
    name: "Hodis",
    checked: false,
    children: []
  },
  {
    term_id: 27,
    name: "Socks",
    checked: false,
    children: []
  }
];
export default function Categoris() {
  const [unSelectedterms, setSelectionTerms] = useState(terms);
  // Adding new state
  const [storeIds, setStoreids] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {}, []);

  const setChecked = (data, id) => {
    data.map((item) => {
      if (item.term_id == id) {
        item.checked = !item.checked;
        //newTerms.push(item)
      }
      if (item.children && item.children.length) {
        setChecked(item.children, id);
      }
    });
  };

  const onchecked = (id) => {
    setChecked(terms, id);
    setSelectionTerms(terms);
    // Checking the existing of the ID
    let tempIds = storeIds.map((item) => item);
    const isExist = tempIds.findIndex((item) => item === id);
    if (isExist === -1) {
      tempIds.push(id);
    } else {
      tempIds = tempIds.filter((item) => item !== id);
    }
    setStoreids(tempIds);
  };

  const recursive = (data, level = 0) => {
    return data.map((item, key) =>
      item.children?.length ? (
        <>
          {renderItem(level, item.name, item.term_id, item.checked, key)}
          {recursive(item.children, level + 1)}
        </>
      ) : (
        renderItem(level, item.name, item.term_id, item.checked, key)
      )
    );
  };

  // Determine the checked value
  const isChecked = (id) => {
    const stored = storeIds.map((item) => item);
    const tempIndex = stored.findIndex((item) => item === id);
    return tempIndex !== -1;
  };

  const renderItem = (level, name, id, checked, key) => (
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={{ flexDirection: "row", alignItems: "center" }}
      key={id}
      onPress={() => {
        onchecked(id);
      }}
    >
      <CheckBox
        // Using the determine function
        value={isChecked(id)}
        onValueChange={() => {
          onchecked(id);
        }}
      />

      <Text style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>
        {level > 0 && " -".repeat(level)} {name}
      </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );

  return <View style={styles.container}>{recursive(unSelectedterms)}</View>;
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  item: {
    fontSize: 20
  },
  container: {
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    padding: 50
  }
});
```